# Why would this jQuery flip function bug with an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

This [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yL9ouscx/5/) is taken from what I am building, on jsFiddle it works without issue. The function flips the card - no problem. However, when running it on my local host the card sometimes (often the first time a card is flipped but then not thereafter) disappears for a few seconds before reappearing. I think this may be related to the fact that there is an image on the front of the card, as this does not disappear. Is there any bug visible in my code, or is there a work around for problems like this perhaps?

The CSS is extensive but I wanted to copy it in exactly as is in case the source of the problem lies therein.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.card-container').on("click", function() {
    $(this).find('.card').toggleClass("flipped");
  });
});
```

```css
.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.card div {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 290px;
  color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card .front {
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: url(../../public/images/card.png) no-repeat;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
}

.card .back {
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: url(../../public/images/card.png) no-repeat;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.reviewflag {
  max-height: 35px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 48%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.carddissappears {
  display: none;
}

.language {
  margin-left: 80%;
}

.cardword {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front" style="background-color: blue;">
      <img class="reviewflag" src="https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/spain/flag-button-round-250.png">
      <p class="cardword">Hola</p>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <p class="cardword">Bonjour</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in fact I'm thinking this is an inaccurate title, as I am not sure that this bug is actually caused by the image.

Comment: it seems that this bug only occurs in google chrome but not in firefox